# How to combine two MySQL queries with different conditions?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different MySQL queries. I need to combine these two queries into one query. I'm trying to get the total sum of cash and card for the given date.

[database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8obQ.png)
Expecting result like :

```
cash : 6666
card : 54657

SELECT SUM(Amount) as totalcash
FROM payment_details 
WHERE date(created) BETWEEN '2018-10-04' AND '2018-10-05' AND paymentMode="CASH";

SELECT SUM(Amount) as totalcard
FROM payment_details 
WHERE date(created) BETWEEN '2018-10-04' AND '2018-10-05' AND paymentMode="CARD";
```

Comment: The condition are the same

Comment: paymentmode are different

Comment: Can you give a sample data

Comment: @executable plz check my attachment in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT paymentMode,SUM(Amount) 
FROM payment_details 
WHERE date(created) BETWEEN '2018-10-04' AND '2018-10-05' AND paymentMode in ('CASH','CARD')
group by paymentMode
```